# Woocommerce Single Product Page: Restore Default Layout/Design

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In many of the tutorials I've read/watched about customizing the single product page, there is an image of the default, standard woocommerce single product page, which looks great without any customization. For some reason, my single product page doesn't look half as good.
https://kingatlaw.attorney/product/civil-litigation/

Does anyone know the reason my single product page doesn't look like the images I'm seeing of the default layout or how to restore the default? In the alternate, is there a place where I can find css/php code I can copy/paste into functions and styles to use their template, rather than wrestling with custom code?

Answer (score 0):

As I am checking with ctrl+shif+i, no error found.

So you should fallow few setps:

1. Backup your single-product.php
2. create woocommerce folder inside your active theme folder

   eg. theme folder -> woocommerce
3. Copy woocommerce plugin template page and paste in the theme folder -> woocommerce

   eg. copy plugins -> woocommerce -> templates -> single-product.php

   and past theme folder -> woocommerce -> single-product.php

Then refresh the page and check it's working or not. if working then you can customize the page.